# Proving an ideal which is maximal in some family to be Prime

Tags: ring-theory

I was trying the following: Let a be a non nilpotent element in a ring $R$ and let $S=\{a,a^2, a^3,...\}$. Suppose $P$ is maximal in the family of all ideals in $R$ that are disjoint from $S$. Then $P$ is a prime ideal.

I am able to prove this in case R is commutative but can we prove it for general ring.

Answer (score 0):

For commutative rings, it holds because an ideal maximal with respect to being disjoint from the multiplicatively closed set $\{a,a^2,a^3\ldots\}$ is prime.

For general rings, the same story is true, except you need [m-systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal#Prime_ideals_for_noncommutative_rings).

So, you could attempt to prove this:

> Proposition: If $M$ is an $m$-system in a ring $R$, and $I$ is an ideal maximal with respect to being disjoint from $M$, then $I$ is a prime ideal.

Start by supposing $aRb\subseteq I$, and $a,b\notin I$, and use the properties of $M$ and $I$ to draw a contradiction.

Comment: Sir, I am still not able to prove.

Comment: @akansha If you tell me where you are stuck, I might be able to help.